# If one captures gradient with Optimizer, will it calculate twice the gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I recently have some training performance bottleneck. I always add a lot of histograms in the summary. I want to know if by calculating gradients first then re-minimizing the lose will calculate twice the gradients. A simplified code:

```
# layers
...
# optimizer
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=logits)
opt = AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
# collect gradients
gradients = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
# train operation
train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
...
# merge summary
...
```

Is there an minimize method in optimizers that use directly the gradients? Something like `opt.minimize(gradients)` instead of `opt.minimize(loss)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply_gradients` after the calculation of the gradients with `compute_gradients` as follows :

```
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: So I DID do twice gradients with that?

Comment: Yup, in your solution above you did calculate the gradients twice, unless there is some internal caching within tensorflow that I don't know of. Anyways, to keep it safe, you should use apply_gradients.